# Reading all numbers in file and calculate their total in python

Tags: python

I am trying to count all numbers in given file. It works unless there is a word between a numbers.
e.g:

```
1
2
car
3
4
```

Here's my code:

```
def main():
count=0
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    try:
        line = f.readline()
        while line != '':
            print(line.strip())
            count += int(line)
            line = f.readline()

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

    print(count)

main()
```

I was thinking about continue, but it does only work with for or while. So is there any way?

Comment: how is your file look like all are in same line????

Comment: what you mean by counting number ? can you tell whats the result for a line like `1 2 car 3 4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `try` and `except` blocks inside your loop. Then when you hit a line with a non-number, you'll just skip it and go on the the next line.

Unrelated to that error, you can also simplify your code a bit by iterating over the file directly in a `for` loop, rather than calling `readline` repeatedly in a `while` loop:

```
with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:          # simpler loop
        print(line.strip())
        try:                # move this inside the loop
            count += int(line)
        except Exception as err: # you may only want to catch ValueErrors here
            print(err)

    print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `isdigit` to check for number:

```
while line != '':
        print(line.strip())
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            count += int(line.strip())
        line = f.readline()
```

Here is Pythonic way to achieve this
if you want to sum all digit:

```
f = open('file')
total_count = sum(int(x) for x in f if x.strip().isdigit())
```

if you want to count how many of them are digit:

```
f = open('file')
total_digit = len(x for x in f if x.strip().isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isdigit` method to check if the line contains only numbers:

```
def main():
    count=0
    with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
        count = sum(int(line) for line in f if line.strip().isdigit())
        print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expressions:

```
import re

total = 0

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line != '':
        total += sum([int(x) for x in re.findall('(\\d+)', line)])
        line = f.readline()
print total
```